# Java : multi threading not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying this program in java but I am not getting any output when I put everything in the `run()` method

Main.java:

```
public class Main {

    static int line;
    static boolean ret = true;
    static BufferedReader br;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File f = new File("tere.dat");
            // boolean ret = f.createNewFile() ;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

            new Test(br.readLine());
            new Test(br.readLine());
    }

}
```

Test.java:

```
public class Test extends Thread {

    private String input;
    static int thread_count = 0;

    public Test(String l)
    {
         input = l;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Checking from other class  : This was printed from file :>>");
        System.out.println(input);
        String upper = input.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The String in all UpperCase :" + upper);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that I want to read lines from a file using two threads and then display whatever I get . I am new to Java

**EDIT** :

I was not using the `start()` method. Though even after using  `start()` It reads only 2 lines from the file and stops. What could be the problem 
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `start()` your Threads.

Also, i would suggest reading a good tutorial on Threads and concurrency in Java before proceeding, as it's a complex subject.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your thread with `start()`  I suggest you not extend Thread but instead implement Runnable.

BTW: Unless you type **impossibly fast**, you won't see the difference in using threads.  It will take about 0.1 milli-seconds to start the thread and finish it so unless you type much faster than that, it will make no difference.

Comment: I know that. But I was just trying to understand the Thread Model :) thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi I suggest you input the two lines before start the threads, or just use hard coded Strings like "Hello" and "World".

Answer (score 1):

You need to start threads:

```
(new Test(br.readLine())).start();
```

And also, you have to add some `join` to wait threads to finish because your main thread will finish execution before created threads.

Comment: Is join really necessary? main thread is done after the two threads are created, so it doesnt need to wait for them to do whatever they do.

Comment: It might finish before the threads, that is what I think partlov is trying to suggest

Answer (score 1):

You have to start them:

```
        (new Test(br.readLine())).start();
        (new Test(br.readLine())).start();
```